Open API 'date' format with UTC timestamp
I have Open API spec that generates model classes and one of the fields expected to be a date and has an example set. [I am unsure if this is a bug since it generates date-time even though we use format:date]
In the spec file, I have this below yaml.
        ExpiryDate:
          type: string
          example: "2024-10-23"
          format: date

But the generated code that keeps updating the expiry date example ApiModelProperty for builds from different timezones and the code generated looks like below.
When an developer builds and commits, it gets updated as below
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "Wed Oct 23 05:30:00 IST 2024")

Same code again gets updated as
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "Tue Oct 22 18:00:00 MDT 2024")

Is there any way I can force openAPI generator to use UTC without altering the date to date-time format?
Note : There is a configuration in pom.xml that has execution step for this code generation which kind of might be the reason but it is required in other places.
<typeMappings>
    <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
<importMappings>
    <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
</importMappings>

I tried to update the example like below based on some blogs which did not actually work and still kept updating the example value or it completely ignores the value.
example: "2024-10-23T00:00:00+00:00"


It probably won’t solve your issue, but you should use LocalDate for a date without time of day. LocalDateTime mentioned in your configuration is exactly a date with time of day (but without time zone or UTC offset).

Am not sure if you are referring to the last line of the code. If so, I am just trying to explain the options that I tried after facing this issue. And the original configuration can be found on the top in code block
